# Modifying arrays during runtime (Java)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that checks if a word is a palindrome.  Is it possible to actively add to an array during runtime?  I want to pull characters from a string into an array of chars to compare them, but I don't know how large the array will have to be.

Comment: "Is it possible to actively add to an array during runtime?" No. Look into using an `ArrayList` instead, which is resizable.

Comment: @resueman can you post that as an answer so I can mark this questions answered?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question is imprecise.  But I think you are asking if it is possible to do an operation that causes the length of an array to change.  The answer to that is No.  (And the question has been asked before .... many times.)

Comment: If you're extracting characters from a String, a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (a mutable sequence of characters) might be a better fit than a `List`.

Comment: Actually, if he is extracting characters from an String, then `toCharArray()` is simpler.

Comment: @StephenC, it of course depends on what the OP is actually doing. `toCharArray()` returns an array which is not "simple" to manipulate.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is char[] myCharArray = str.toCharArray();

Comment: @MickMnemonic - Last time I checked, a palindrome is the same length in both directions :-)

Comment: @StephenC Thanks.  I used that and it, well, half-worked.